# How to make date turnoff dynamically in jquery datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery

hello  i want to turnoff  date    dynamically in jquery `datepicker`,  but the problem is that how can i pass variable from one function to another. here is the code.

```
<script>
    $(function() {

        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                var day = date.getDate();
                if (day == 31) /* i want to pass dynamic value here */ {
                    return [false];
                } else {
                    return [true];
                };
            }
        });

        $(".ui-state-default").on('click', function(e) {
            var value = e.toElement.outerText; /* i want to pass this value to beforeShowDay*/
        })
    });
</script>
```

check my demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/epHNZ/585)**

Comment: If you want to pass a value from one function to another, and im guessing you arent calling the function, so you cant return it. I would use a Global Variable. To make a variable global you need to take the "var" our when initializing it, or put the variable outside the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just declare value outside of click method. And replace 31 to value. After that, it will work.

```
$(function(){ 
    var value;

   $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
     beforeShowDay: function(date){
     var day=date.getDate();
      if (day==value)/* i want to pass dynamic value here */{
       return [false];
      } else{
       return [true];
      }; 



       }});

 $( ".ui-state-default" ).on('click',function(e){
        value= e.toElement.outerText; /* i want to pass this value to beforeShowDay*/
         })
 });
```

Comment: thanx you Sherali Turdiyev

Answer (score 1):

Easy peasy:

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/epHNZ/586/)

```
denyDate = 12;  // <-- just that easy

$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var day=date.getDate();
        if (day==denyDate)/* <-- use it here */{
            return [false];
        }else{
            return [true];
        }
    }
});

$( ".ui-state-default" ).on('click',function(e){
    value= e.toElement.outerText; /* i want to pass this value to beforeShowDay*/
})
```

---

Update: I misunderstood the question (did not read carefully) and missed the key point that OP desired denyDate to be set in the `.on(click)` function. For this answer to be correct, it had to look like this:

```
var denyDate;  // <-- denyDate gets its value below

$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var day=date.getDate();
        if (day==denyDate)/* <-- use it here */{
            return [false];
        }else{
            return [true];
        }
    }
});

$( ".ui-state-default" ).on('click',function(e){
    denyDate = e.toElement.outerText; /***** <=== THIS IS THE CHANGE *****/
});
```

Sherali Turdiyev understood, though, and he got the right answer. Well done Sherali.

Comment: Your edit was correct saroj, but 3 reviewers did not understand what you were changing (and why) so they rejected the changes. I also did not read the question closely enough, but Sherali Turdiyev did and he was able to provide the correct answer. Using `value` for a variable name was a little bit confusing, but Sherali understood. +1 to Sherali. :)

Answer (score 1):

The beforeShowDay option is expecting a callback function with specific parameters, so you can't just pass your own value. However, you could make a global variable or create a hidden input field which stores a value, either of which can be referenced inside your function.

Here's an example using a hidden input field. The field will not be visible to the user, and the value can be updated at any time via JavaScript/jQuery (as shown in the click event handler).

http://jsfiddle.net/mwatz122/j3eq4q7c/1/

HTML:

```
Date:
<div id="datepicker"></div>
<input id="beforeShowDayValue" type="hidden" value="5" />
```

JS:

```
$(function () {

    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var day = date.getDate();
            if (day == $('#beforeShowDayValue').val()) /* i want to pass dynamic value here */
            {
                return [false];
            } else {
                return [true];
            };
        }
    });

    $(".ui-state-default").on('click', function (e) {
        $('#beforeShowDayValue').val('31'); /* i want to pass this value to beforeShowDay*/
    })
});
```

Comment: hello Matthew i edited code and link and it works just fine thanx

Answer (score -1):

setting global variable work for me

check my demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/j3eq4q7c/15/)**

```
 $(function () {

  var value;/* setting global variable  */

         $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
          minDate:0,
           beforeShowDay: function(date){
           var day=date.getDate();
            if (day==value)/* passing dynamic value here from datepicker event */{
             return [false];
            } else{
             return [true];
            }; 



             }});
$(".ui-state-default").on('click', function (e) {
   value= e.toElement.outerText;
  })

});
```